# signinwithemailandpassword failed first argument email must be a valid string (Angular, Firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I searched for this question here and on the web, but nothing Works for me.

When I want to log in, this is the error I got: "signinwithemailandpassword failed first argument email must be a valid string". I know that it is not a full login, but I don't want to go further because this is not work.

The codes:

service:

```
signIn(email, password) {
    return this.aFA.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }
```

signIn component ts:

```
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private aS: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  signIn(f) {
    let data = f.value
    this.aS.signIn(data.email, data.password)
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
}
```

signIn component html:

```
<div class="body">
    <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signIn(f)">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required>

        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required>

        <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reactive-form` in the following way:

```
<div class="body">
    <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signIn()">
        <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="email" required>

        <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="password" required>

        <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then in the ts:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, } from '@angular/forms';

export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
 ngForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(private aS: AuthenticationService, private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    ngForm = this.fb.group({
    email   : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  signIn() {
    if(this.ngForm.valid){
    this.aS.signIn(this.ngForm.value.email, this.ngForm.value.password)
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
   }
  }
}
```

Read the following:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#overview-of-reactive-forms

Comment: Yes, I had to use reactive-form, but not how you made it. Or just I was wrong. Luckily I found how to make it work